# Cannot upgrade Magento from 2.4.2 to 2.4.2-p1 using Composer 2

Tags: upgrade, composer, magento2.4.2

I have upgraded Magento community edition from version 2.4.1 to 2.4.2 using Composer version 1. Magento 2.4.2 supports Composer 2 (see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-2.html).

I am trying to upgrade to the 2.4.2-p1 security patch using Composer 2, but it does not seem possible.

When I run
`composer show magento/product-community-edition --all | grep -m 1 versions`
using Composer 2, I get the following output
`versions : * 2.4.2`

When I run the same command with Composer 1, the output is 
`versions : 2.4.2-p1, * 2.4.2, 2.4.1-p1, 2.4.1, 2.4.0-p1, 2.4.0, 2.3.7, 2.3.6-p1, 2.3.6, 2.3.5-p2, 2.3.5-p1, 2.3.5, 2.3.4-p2, 2.3.4, 2.3.3-p1, 2.3.3, 2.3.2-p2, 2.3.2, 2.3.1, 2.3.0, 2.2.11, 2.2.10, 2.2.9, 2.2.8, 2.2.7, 2.2.6, 2.2.5, 2.2.4, 2.2.3, 2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.2.0-rc30, 2.2.0-rc23, 2.2.0-rc22, 2.2.0-rc21, 2.2.0-rc20, 2.1.18, 2.1.17, 2.1.16, 2.1.15, 2.1.14, 2.1.13, 2.1.12, 2.1.11, 2.1.10, 2.1.9, 2.1.8, 2.1.7, 2.1.6, 2.1.5, 2.1.4, 2.1.3, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.0-rc3, 2.1.0-rc2, 2.1.0-rc1, 2.0.18, 2.0.17, 2.0.16, 2.0.15, 2.0.14, 2.0.13, 2.0.12, 2.0.11, 2.0.10, 2.0.9, 2.0.8, 2.0.7, 2.0.6, 2.0.5, 2.0.4, 2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 0.42.0-beta7`

This implies that the only Magento version you can install using Composer 2 is Magento 2.4.2.

Or perhaps I need to make some change to my composer.json?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Please try below command:

> composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.2-p1
> --no-update

After running above commands, composer.json and composer.lock file will update,
Now you can run composer update command:

> composer update

Hope this solution will help you.
Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Faisal. Requiring the 2.4.2-p1 version as you suggest works even though it is not listed as an available version. I was able to upgrade from 2.4.2 to 2.4.2-p1 successfully using Composer 2. Thanks again for your contribution.

Comment: Hello @bpbrooe if you find this solution is helpful, please accept it as solution. So that it can help others